# Why is the CUPS printer not printing anything when too many jobs are active?

Tags: printing

I get the following error message:

/usr/bin/lpr: Too many active jobs.

and nothing prints

I can hit <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and then it starts working again

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/cupsd` will show you CUPS logs, `ps -fu lp` will show you all processes CUPS has, `sudo --user lp ls -l /var/log/cups' will show you the actual CUPS logs, `sudo --user lp zless /var/spool/cups/*` will let you read them. In addition, `CUPS` has its own website http://www.CUPS.org

Answer (score 1):

CUPS may be using one the builtin resource usage limitations. These could be compiled-in default values, or explicitely set ones which you can both change/override in */etc/cups/cupsd.conf*.

You should check for the following values in */etc/cups/cupsd.conf*:

```
FilterLimit
MaxClients
MaxClientsPerHost
MaxJobs
MaxJobsPerPrinter
MaxJobsPerUser
```

Look up the meaning of each of these settings by reading *'man cupsd.conf'*.

My guess is that by setting

```
MaxClients 100
MaxClientsPerHost 10
MaxJobs 1000
MaxJobsPerUser 500
MaxJobsPerPrinter 500
MaxJobsPerClient 500
```

will go a long way to solve your immediate problem. But you ***still*** should investigate, why the default values do not work for your system (unless someone, for some reason, changed them some time ago to very low values).